# Is there any point in declaring arguments as [In] when PInvoking?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

When using platform invokes, does specifying arguments as `[In]` make a difference in how the runtime approaches these?

For instance, when PInvoking `CreateRemoteThread`, `lpThreadId` is specified as `out` as per the article on MSDN:

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateRemoteThread(
  _In_   HANDLE hProcess,
  _In_   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_   SIZE_T dwStackSize,
  _In_   LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_   LPVOID lpParameter,
  _In_   DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_  LPDWORD lpThreadId
);
```

And all other arguments are `_In_`. In my C# code, I handle that specific function like so:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRemoteThread", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        uint dwStackSize,
        IntPtr lpStartAddress,
        IntPtr lpParameter,
        uint dwCreationFlags,
        [Out] IntPtr lpThreadId);
```

Adding the `[Out]` attribute to `lpThreadId` so the runtime knows to marshal it back to the caller. Would the runtime handle my function any different if I'd change the function signature to this:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRemoteThread", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(
        [In] IntPtr hProcess,
        [In] IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
        [In] uint dwStackSize,
        [In] IntPtr lpStartAddress,
        [In] IntPtr lpParameter,
        [In] uint dwCreationFlags,
        [Out] IntPtr lpThreadId);
```

Or would it be the exact same thing; are arguments considered `[In]` by default?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute.aspx

Comment: You'd want to `out` or `ref` that last one. But `[In]` on its own [only really matters when marshalling `ref` data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx).

Comment: @user7116 not actually true, anything that is marshaled as a pointer should use the `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes.

Comment: @Mgetz Is that only important for pointers, and if so, why?

Comment: @aevitas pointers as in `string` and any `struct`s passed in e.g. any data structures other than primitive types.

Comment: `[In]` is the default for most things (even for `string`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes actually are very important, they tell the framework whether or not it needs to concern itself with marshaling a parameter in a particular direction. This is particularly useful for things like `structs` which are very expensive to marshal. By default the framework assumes that marshaling is bidirectional, which may have a large performance impact.

#### Update:

Some of the comments have brought up the fact that primitive types are marshaled as `[In]` by default, this is correct. However the fact that marshaling is complicated gives onus to being as explicit as possible in PInvoke declarations, leave as little as possible to the framework to decide even it it is already supposed to be that way.

Comment: So if I get your answer right, specifying arguments as `[In]` tells the runtime that it won't ever need to marshal these values back to the caller, and therefore should theoretically improve performance?

Comment: @aevitas correct, it tells the framework that the parameter is marshaled in one direction only.

Comment: `[In]` is the default for most parameter types.

Comment: @user7116 incorrect, `[In, Out]` is the default for everything non-primitive.

Comment: @Mgetz: I'll just leave this here, you don't have to [read it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77e6taeh.aspx) if you don't want to. http://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC171879.gif

Comment: I'm aware, I'm also aware of the marshaling best practices, and the fact that it's not that simple. These comments are no longer constructive.

Comment: Actually `string` is a poor example since it is always `[In]` and cannot be marshalled `[Out]` even if you ask for that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought so too... but I got heap corruption and finally figured out that was what was happening. But I understand your point. My point coincides with the CLR team's recommendation of being descriptive as possible with PInvokes as to leave nothing to the framework to decide.

Comment: @Mgetz: I don't disagree you should include your intent for expressiveness. I disagree with your incorrect assertions about `[In, Out]` being the default. I'll say it one last time (and use bold to help): **If you do not specify `ref` or `out` your parameter is marshalled `[In]` by default.**

Comment: (with the amendment for `StringBuilder` and the handful of other classes which the Marshaller special cases)